# catkin build with multi-core make for building individual packages

Tags: ros

I have multiple libraries and the main program. 
When I run `catkin build` command it starts with 8 jobs but after finishing building libraries continues to build the main program only using 1 job (one CPU core).

How do I force `catkin build` to distribute multiple cores on building each individual libs?

Answer (score 1):

```
catkin build -j15 --make-args="-j5"
```

uses 15 make jobs with 5 processes each.